# Python on OS X can't see most recent numpy

Tags: python, macos, numpy, matplotlib

`easy_install -U numpy`

When trying to use matplotlib on `Mac OS X 10.7.5`, it appears that `Python` is always finding an older version of `numpy`, not the binary release I install from the `SourceForge` site.

When I try:

```
>>> from matplotlib import pyplot
```

I get:

```
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 6 but this version of numpy is 4
```

(and a lot more error-tracing)

I looked for answers and tried:

```
sudo easy_install -U numpy
```

which had worked for others in my situation, despite errors when it ran. My error was:

```
RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program
/tmp/easy_install-tntLIw/numpy-1.6.2/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py:252: RuntimeWarning: Parent module 'numpy.distutils' not found while handling absolute import
```

and I'm still unable to use `matplotlib`, and Python still reports seeing `numpy version 1.5.1`

A variety of attempts to install pre-built Python combos such as `scipy`, `superpack` all yield the same result.

I'd appreciate some help and advice.

Comment: Try install numpy using virtualenv: http://spencersthesis.wordpress.com/2012/03/27/setting-up-python-scipy-numpy-on-mac-os-x-10-6-8/ - doing easy_install against system Python is not recommended. sudo easy_install is something you should **never ever** do.

Comment: Thanks Mikko. I will never use easy_install again. Is there any way to see if I did any damage? If I did, what you would suggest for getting back to a clean slate? I like the virtual environment strategy you suggest, and will give that a try as soon as I can. I appreciate your help.

Comment: No damage done. It's just sudo easy_install = impossible to uninstall.

Comment: More (also see comments): http://jamiecurle.co.uk/blog/installing-pip-virtualenv-and-virtualenvwrapper-on-os-x

Comment: Which versions of gcc and python are you using? Where are they installed? How did you install them?